# Documenting tool for a Programming Language itself

Tags: documentation, programming-languages, self-documenting-code

At first I thought about using doxygen for my needs, but then I realized that would be better to have some open source online tool to describe a programming language itself. For example, the official PHP documentation looks perfect. It has:

- Support of documenting in many natural languages:

[image: PHP documentation in many natural languages]

- Support for different versions of programming language
- Version Changelogs that can be even for each function
- Community driven comments and examples:

[image: PHP Community comments and examples]

However, I have only come across static generators so far and have been unable to find a tool that meets my needs. Can anyone provide any information?

Comment: There is a related question on the language design site which is currently in beta - https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28/how-might-one-formally-communicate-define-describe-a-programming-language-design